# Prevent function from running when a variable changes in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a form with a checkbox and text input.

```
const [formVars, setFormVars] = useState<any>({checkbox:true})
const submitForm = () => {
  console.log({formVars})
}

render (
  <Checkbox checked={formVars.checkbox} /> Bake the cookies?
  <TextInput label="what kind of cookies?" />
  <Button onClick={() => submitForm()}
)
```

`submitForm` should not run until the user clicks submit, however my code seems to be producing a never-ending loop where the form changes formVars, and the change sets off submitForm. How can I prevent this?

Comment: You're missing a `>` for your arrow function inside of the `onClick` callback property of your `Button` component. Is this just a c/p mistake or ... ?

Comment: @Kapobajza Yes, that was a typo, thanks for pointing it out. But not the cause of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of typos in the question, so I created a simple copy of your code.

The button's onClick prop takes a callback, not a function call. You're likely calling the submit function instead of passing it to the button onClick prop.

Here's how you trigger the submission manually for controlled inputs

```
export default function App() {
  const [formVars, setFormVars] = useState({ checkbox: true });
  const submitForm = (e) => {
    console.log({ formVars });
  };
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFormVars(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <label>
        Name:
        <input onChange={handleChange} type="text" name="name" />
      </label>
      <button onClick={submitForm}>submit</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<Button onClick={()=> submitForm}
```

Try this syntax for the button

Comment: most linters will let you know that you have an unused statement by referencing a function and not calling it and not passing it to anything else.